# Nokia s60 emulator for linux

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation, nokia, s60

I am using EclipseMe on Ubuntu. I want an emulator that can emulate mouse movements on screen.

Is there an s60 emulator for linux?

Edit:
Does net beans has an in built emulator that can emulate mouse movement on device screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans uses the Sun Wireless Toolkit.

The JavaME emulator it contains can me made into a touchscreen emulator. Read the accompanying documentation, it should be as simple as setting a variable inside a configuration file before stating the emulator.

You can find the specification for MIDP (the top layer of the JavaME platform you're probably targetting) at http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=118

Look at the javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas class, you will find several methods used to deal with "pointer". While they are more often used to handle touchscreen event, they also map to mouse/joystick clicks on emulators.

You can definitely get the MIDP pointerDragged events when running the emulator on Linux.

This is basic MIDP, no need for fancy JSR-226 (e-swt) support.

Comment: Is this part of the SWT or added net beans functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows only Symbian Emulator (EPOC) is being scrapped for a QEMU based emulator that will run on all platforms. This will likely be available within 6 months or so.

At the moment, I run Windows XP inside VirtualBox on my Mac for Symbian development. It works fine, but is of course not the ideal solution.

Answer (score -1):

The full symbian OS emulator with application interfaces for Java and Symbian C is windows based unfortunately.

I usually get a MS Windows Vista install disk and install that into a VM like VirtualBox and than install the symbian SDks on top of that..

Works best on those 4 core desktop 64-bit computers now on sale for $687 as you get access to full 8 gig ram and close to 1 terabyte hard drive..